# how to handle comma(,) if it occurs inside value

Tags: opencsv

I am just start using openCSV. I want to ask suppose i have a csv file in which `,` is present within the value like

```
abc, def, ghi, j,kl, mno
```

note the `j,kl`is a column value with `,` in between. How can i handle such situation?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you've adopted a sane convention (e.g. values containing commas must appear inside `'` or `"` quote marks), there's no way for a computer, in general, to divine which of those commas are separators, and which of them are meant to be parts of values.

Comment: (Or unless your CSV file is, in fact, a fixed format file in disguise, e.g. the commas always appear at positions 3, 8, 13 and 19 in each row, and are thus purely decorative)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever actually it's just a dummy content. I just start using opencsv and unfortunately the first question that ask to me is this :-). So it's ok. I answer that if this is situation then try to contain values with in `""` or `'` :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual procedure is to contain the values within quotes (") e.g. "abc", "def", "ghi", "j,kl", "mno" or delimit by something other and less used than a comma.

Comment: Can you please tell me one thing, that if the contents are like `abc, def, ghi, "j,kl", mno`, then it is ok ? In such case how can i handle ? Thanks?

Comment: If you create a CSV like that then it should work.  Not sure what you mean by "how can I handle"